Can someone explain: Er sah seine Felle davonschwimmen?
In  context it seems to mean 'He realised that his strategy was not working', but where do the skins or hides come in?

"seine Felle davonschwimmen sehen" indicates that some profit is near reach and likely, but is thwarded by some intermediate unfortunate/adverse incident. A very common expression is "er sah schon seine Felle davonschwimmen" = he already imagined losing at his gains...

It comes from tanning This requires a lot of water and was therefore done in rivers. If workers were not careful, the current of the river could take the skins with it and all the hard work was lost. The last part is essential here. You use this idiom if you already had (considerable) work invested.

This, and several related expressions, have entries in DWDS, for example here. A rough translation into English might be "to see one's fortune slipping away", but of course the exact phrasing would depend on the situation and context. It might be worth noting that this seems rare in spoken language, for example DWDS shows 25 hits for "davonschwimmen && Felle" in Wikipedia, but 0 under subtitles.

@RDBury for what it's worth I've never heard or read it, but it was easy enough to guess from context.
